# Configure Chef server 11 on Debian machine

Tags: configuration, automation, debian, chef-infra

I try tu use Chef on debian machine (version 8 : Jessy).
I have installed Chef with this command :

```
apt-get install chef chef-server
```

After, I try to configure Knife with this command :

```
knife configure -i
```

At the end of the configuration I have this error :

```
ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef-server/admin.pem
Check your configuration file ensure that your private key is readable
```

In the repository /etc/chef I have only one file : "client.rb" .

Can you help me ?

Samuel

PS: Sorry for my bad English (I'm french ;) )

Comment: Which apt repo are you using? The one from *apt.opscode.com* don't use that anymore, it's only for old Chef 10 versions. If you've put the Chef 11 *.deb* in an own repo, ignore this warning.

Comment: I have used aptitude, but I don't use the repo *apt.opscode.com*.
I will reinstall chef with this repo.

Comment: No, DON'T use that repo. It offers you only old versions. Go to the [downloads](http://www.getchef.com/chef/install/) page and get the *.deb* there (I know that sucks... I'd prefer to get them through an official apt repo, too, but this way you can only put it into an own repo).

Comment: But I have a Debian machine and on the download page we have Chef Server only for _Ubuntu_ or _Ubuntu Enterprise_ ...

Comment: Rectification : on the download page of Chef server, they specify that the `.deb` file is compatible for Debian.

Comment: Yes, just use older Ubuntu versions (11.04 is what I think what we're using)

Comment: In [Chef docs](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef10/Installing+Chef+Server+on+Debian+or+Ubuntu+using+Packages) they use the GPG key `83EF826A` and I use the Debian catalogue `keyring.debian.org`. But that don't work !

Comment: As the URL says, this is only the old Chef 10 version. Don't use that. Chef 11 is the current version and there is no official apt repo available for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Chef Server 11, you have to run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure`, which then extracts the server. This is described in the [docs](http://docs.opscode.com/install_server.html) and should also be emitted after installing the debian package.